# Rerender lightning component when account is saved

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, lightning, lightning-experience

I have a custom checkbox field. I have a lightning component placed on related list tab in the lightning page. When the checkbox field in details page is changed and saved I want to rerender the lightning component which is in the related list tab. I have tried e.force:refreshview event but its not working.
I placed the component on details page and tried. Didn't work.
Is there any way to do this.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ? I am facing similar issue.